# Calling a spinner from an activity to an Adapter class

Tags: android

So I have this Spinner which is made up of currency, and I want to display the right selected currency on my layout. Here is the sample. So I have the spinner in a different activity my question is how can I get my spinner from

> ExpenseActivity

To my ExpenseAdapter

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GeneralViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == -1) {
            MonthSummaryCard holder1 = (MonthSummaryCard) holder;
            holder1.setWalletAmountView(" $" + Double.valueOf(walletBalance).toString());
            holder1.setTotalExpensesPerMonth(" $" + Double.valueOf(totalExpenseAmount).toString());
```

Instead of entering the dollar sign I want to append all different Currencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try simply creating a secondary constructor for your adapter class where you pass the result of your spinner...i.e.

```
String currencyType = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
ExpenseAdapter expenseAdapter = new ExpenseAdapter(... , currencyType);
```

then in your ExpenseAdapter constructor...

```
this.currencyType = currencyType;
```

and in your above code...

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GeneralViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == -1) {
        MonthSummaryCard holder1 = (MonthSummaryCard) holder;
        holder1.setWalletAmountView(currencyType + Double.valueOf(walletBalance).toString());
        holder1.setTotalExpensesPerMonth(currencyType + Double.valueOf(totalExpenseAmount).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear but what i understand is this:
You can pass the spinner instance to the adapter throw the adapter constructor then you can change its proprieties from inside onBindViewHolder()